# Syncing much faster on 11.04 than in 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I am using two computers, one with Ubuntu 10.10 and one with 11.04. The computer with Ubuntu 11.04 is syncing files very fast with Ubuntu One. The computer with 10.10 installed takes forever. Is there any way I can speed up syncing with Ubuntu One on my 10.10 computer?

Comment: Is it the same number of files of the same size? Or is the concern the actual transfer rate.

Answer (score 3):

We've made a lot of improvements to file sync speed that landed in 11.04; we'll be making those changes available to everything back to 10.04 in a few months' time.

Comment: Is there any more specifik timeline for the improvements for 10.10? I really like Ubuntu One as it is integrated in Ubuntu. At the same time Drop Box is faster, more stable and also includes encryption. I am finding it harder and harder to pay for the extended space in Ubuntu One due to the many problems with the service. Hopefully the problems will be resolved soon!